# One recipient complete after others can't sign in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a template in Docusign UI side. After that added relevent fields with the signature field.
Then I used that template's id in my code side and sent it.
I have sent it to multiple recipients.
My question is if one recipient finished it others can't sign.It's showing as template edit page for others.Why is that. But I can send it through docusign site.then others can sign.

Here is the way in template UI side recipient role added
[image]

Here is the c# code

```
 string templateId = _docusignConfig.ACHDocTemplateId;
 EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
 env.TemplateId = templateId;
 env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>();
 TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
 signer1.Email = signerEmail;
 signer1.Name = signerName;
 signer1.RoleName = "signers";
 env.TemplateRoles.Add(signer1);
 env.Status = "sent";
 string accountId = _docusignConfig.AccountId;
 string basePath = _docusignConfig.BaseURL;
 var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
 apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
 var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
 EnvelopeSummary result = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, env);
```

What can be the issue here?

Note: In here I'm sending signing request when users registering.While registering I'm getting their email and username and sending it

Comment: I only see one signer/recipient in your code?
Also, not clear how are they signing, I assume they receive an email? is that supposed to be a signing group? (I see "signers" plural)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,In this system this signing request need to send when some users registering time.When registering that user receive an email.In this code I have added that part.In here not sending all the recipients to emails at once.

Comment: I still don't understand. I only see one recipient. You said two. Are you saying you do this more than once? again and again you create new envelopes from the same template and the next one can't sign?

Comment: Assume this code is execute once user click a button.One clicks means one new user.Yes I did this more than once.If one recipient finished others can't sign ,others to show the template in designer view

Comment: do you use embedded signing?

Comment: What is embedded signing? I only added that signature field to my template

Comment: what email addresses do you use ? real ones? or test ones?

Comment: valid email addresses I have used

Answer (score 0):

Your role is misconfigured on the server template.

You need to clear out the "name" field in order to be able to populate it through the API. Also, your "Role" doesn't match the role you are defining in your API call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, RoleName is same in both places

Comment: Seems it's sdk side issue, it's doesn't allow user to sign if another recipient finished it.I have resolved it using RestAPIs

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using?